# Mixed integer programming formulation for Ising model

Tags: co.combinatorics, integer-programming, combinatorial-optimization

I want to implement a minimisation on a 2D spin Ising model with 30x30 grid. The spin variables is 0,1 and the objective is to minimize the sum of products of spins. For simplicity, I only include NN pair interaction and a "triangular" interaction term. The formulation I give is as followed. And I wish to ask for suggestions whether there would be some stronger formulation that could make computation faster. Thank you :D

the original objective is:

$$\sum\limits_{i = 1}^{29} {\sum\limits_{j = 1}^{30} {{J_1}{s_{i,j}}{s_{i + 1,j}}} }  + \sum\limits_{i = 1}^{30} {\sum\limits_{j = 1}^{29} {{J_1}{s_{i,j}}{s_{i,j + 1}}} }  + \sum\limits_{i = 1}^{29} {\sum\limits_{j = 1}^{29} {{J_3}{s_{i,j}}{s_{i + 1,j}}{s_{i,j + 1}}} } $$

$${s_{i,j}} \in \{ 0,1\} $$

we linearize it so that:

[\begin{align}
  & \min : \\ 
 & \sum\limits_{i=1}^{29}{\sum\limits_{j=1}^{30}{{{J}_{1}}{{s}_{i,j,1}}}}+\sum\limits_{i=1}^{30}{\sum\limits_{j=1}^{29}{{{J}_{1}}{{s}_{i,j,2}}}}+\sum\limits_{i=1}^{29}{\sum\limits_{j=1}^{29}{{{J}_{3}}{{s}_{i,j,3}}}} \\ 
 & \text{subject to:} \\ 
 & \forall i=1...29\,j=1...30\,\ k=1...4 \\ 
 & \left[ \begin{matrix}
   {{s}_{i,j}}  \\
   {{s}_{i+1,j}}  \\
   {{s}_{i,j,1}}  \\
\end{matrix} \right]={{y}_{i,j,1,1}}\left[ \begin{matrix}
   0  \\
   0  \\
   0  \\
\end{matrix} \right]+{{y}_{i,j,1,2}}\left[ \begin{matrix}
   1  \\
   0  \\
   0  \\
\end{matrix} \right]+{{y}_{i,j,1,3}}\left[ \begin{matrix}
   0  \\
   1  \\
   0  \\
\end{matrix} \right]+{{y}_{i,j,1,4}}\left[ \begin{matrix}
   1  \\
   1  \\
   1  \\
\end{matrix} \right] \\ 
 & \sum\limits_{k=1}^{4}{{{y}_{i,j,1,k}}=1} \\ 
 & 0\le y\le 1 \\ 
 & {{y}_{i,j,1,k}}\text{ is integral} \\ 
 &  \\ 
 & \forall i=1...30\,j=1...29\,\,k=1...4 \\ 
 & \left[ \begin{matrix}
   {{s}_{i,j}}  \\
   {{s}_{i,j+1}}  \\
   {{s}_{i,j,1}}  \\
\end{matrix} \right]={{y}_{i,j,2,1}}\left[ \begin{matrix}
   0  \\
   0  \\
   0  \\
\end{matrix} \right]+{{y}_{i,j,2,2}}\left[ \begin{matrix}
   1  \\
   0  \\
   0  \\
\end{matrix} \right]+{{y}_{i,j,2,3}}\left[ \begin{matrix}
   0  \\
   1  \\
   0  \\
\end{matrix} \right]+{{y}_{i,j,2,4}}\left[ \begin{matrix}
   1  \\
   1  \\
   1  \\
\end{matrix} \right] \\ 
 & \sum\limits_{k=1}^{4}{{{y}_{i,j,2,k}}=1} \\ 
 & 0\le {{y}_{i,j,2,k}}\le 1 \\ 
 & {{y}_{i,j,2,k}}\text{ is integral} \\ 
 &  \\ 
 & \forall i=1...29\,j=1...29\,\,k=1...8 \\ 
 & \left[ \begin{matrix}
   {{s}_{i,j}}  \\
   {{s}_{i+1,j}}  \\
   {{s}_{i,j+1}}  \\
   {{s}_{i,j,3}}  \\
\end{matrix} \right]={{y}_{i,j,3,1}}\left[ \begin{matrix}
   0  \\
   0  \\
   0  \\
   0  \\
\end{matrix} \right]+{{y}_{i,j,3,2}}\left[ \begin{matrix}
   1  \\
   0  \\
   0  \\
   0  \\
\end{matrix} \right]+{{y}_{i,j,3,3}}\left[ \begin{matrix}
   0  \\
   1  \\
   0  \\
   0  \\
\end{matrix} \right]+{{y}_{i,j,3,4}}\left[ \begin{matrix}
   1  \\
   1  \\
   0  \\
   0  \\
\end{matrix} \right]+{{y}_{i,j,3,5}}\left[ \begin{matrix}
   0  \\
   0  \\
   1  \\
   0  \\
\end{matrix} \right]+{{y}_{i,j,3,6}}\left[ \begin{matrix}
   1  \\
   0  \\
   1  \\
   0  \\
\end{matrix} \right]+{{y}_{i,j,3,7}}\left[ \begin{matrix}
   0  \\
   1  \\
   1  \\
   0  \\
\end{matrix} \right]+{{y}_{i,j,3,8}}\left[ \begin{matrix}
   1  \\
   1  \\
   1  \\
   1  \\
\end{matrix} \right] \\ 
 & \sum\limits_{k=1}^{8}{{{y}_{i,j,3,k}}=1} \\ 
 & 0\le {{y}_{i,j,3,k}}\le 1 \\ 
 & {{y}_{i,j,3,k}}\text{ is integral} \\ 
 &  \\ 
 & \forall i=1...30\,j=1...30 \\ 
 & 0\le {{s}_{i,j}}\le 1 \\ 
 & {{s}_{i,j}}\quad \text{integral} \\ 
\end{align}]

Comment: You probably don't want to reinvent the wheel, especially when it comes to Ising model simulation. I would suggest looking at Metropolis (Monte Carlo) implementations or cluster algorithms like Swendsen/Wang.

Comment: Actually, we don't want to do monte carlo on spin systems. The problem for monte carlo is that, it could not give me the true ground state for certain and it could not provide an bound on how low energy the true ground state would possibly be. Thank you :D

Comment: http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/q/14130/4274.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was cross-posted and answered at another site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is studied in Condensed Matter. You may wish to look at Projected Entangled Pair States - the 2D generalization of famous Density Matrix Renormalization Group / Matrix Product States ansatz. The recent development is reported in http://arxiv.org/abs/1405.3259 but do consider references therein as well.

Comment: So are they really solving exactly the same problem??? with decision variables being the spins and they are trying to minimizing over spin configurations (where spins can only be 0,1)??? Thank you very much:)

Comment: They optimize over wavefunction, which is a linear combination of all possible states, $2^{30 \times 30}$ in your case. You seem to restrict this to pure states only.

Comment: Uhm... Interesting, I believe they include quadratic terms like s[1,1]*s[1,2], do they also include triplet terms like s[1,1]*s[1,2]*s[2,2]? It's rather difficult for me to infer from their equations, due to different background.... thank you very much :)

Comment: They include pairwise interactions, but I doubt it comes to triples. Anyway, the PEPS technique itself is applicable to any interaction pattern.

Comment: Once again thank you very much:) but do you know what kind of optimization branch in mathematics do they use (is it monte carlo or integer programming)? Or do they start anew solely from condense matter physics? Do you think their methods is general the area of optimization and applicable to the naive looking problem I have? Really thank you very much:)

Comment: The DMRG / MPS methods arose in quantum physics. The idea was unknown to Maths community for quite some time and was rediscovered under the name Tensor Trains. On this you may wish to check the intro and references in my recent paper 10.1016/j.cpc.2013.12.017

Comment: It's great! Thank you very much again:) But it seems it would be very hard for me to implement it in near future without digging into the formulation.........

Comment: One final remark and question: initially, I don't want to do monte carlo because it could not give a lower bound and upper bound as in integer programming. Do you think this method could provide this bound and the gap would close as computation proceeds? Thank you again very much :)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, one way I realize is to use this kind of constraints:
$${s_i} + {s_j} - 1 \le {s_i}*{s_j} \le {s_i}$$